# Interpersonal children?

Tags: discussion, scope

Took a look at this question:

[Should I have my child apologize to someone after he called them fat?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/4238/1921)

and I did a double take.

> *This definitely belongs on parenting...* my brain tells me.
>   *No brain,* I say, *it's...* my brain seems to have stumped me. *Interpersonal relationships, just with children?*

Help assuage my brain! What belongs on Parenting and what on IPS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with things being on-topic on more than one Stack Exchange site. There are plenty of examples of overlap between Stack Exchange sites, such as the overlap between [Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://fantasy.stackexchange.com) and [Movies and TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/). There is no inherent problem with this, and no reason why this would be a bad thing.

Let's let Parenting do their thing, and we'll do our thing. Parenting will make decisions about their scope based on what is good for parenting, and we'll make decisions about our scope based on what is good for us. If that means that there are questions that can be asked on both sites, then so be it.

Comment: Moreover, interactions involving children *are* interpersonal interactions. Children are the grown-ups of the future.

Comment: I'd also add "please don't cross-post the same question on two sites at the same time though".

Comment: Might want to add that it is up to the OP to decide which of the related Stacks they ask the question.